# How to extract lines starting with a certain letter?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a texfile with a many lines in it, Example lines:

```
AABBA, 10050, Tom marc Peter , POR
BBBAC, 10051, Eva braun, AUS
CCAHA, 10052, Jon murry , UDD
GGHAN, 10053, Taler yon, AGG
IIUSA, 10054, Raff paleen , EUS
UUGAS, 10055, Bara enty, ESP
```

I would like to extract lines featuring a person whose last name starts with a P.

output:

```
AABBA, 10050, Tom marc peter , POR
IIUSA, 10054, Raff paleen , EUS
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{ n=split($3,a," "); if(tolower(substr(a[n],0,1))=="p") print $0; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the number of commas and working back to a word beginning with p/P, you can do this with "any" regular expression program. For instance

```
grep -E '^([^,]+,){2,2}[^,]+[[:space:]][pP][^[:space:],]+[[:space:]]*,' mytextfile
```

gives

```
AABBA, 10050, Tom marc Peter , POR
IIUSA, 10054, Raff paleen , EUS
```

Comment: Do you also know a command for extr4ct All lines fe4turing a p3rson whose name cont4ins three words.?

Comment: My example only used the commas, and assumes the last name is the last word before the comma.  If you had a compound last name (such as "Van der Pool"), that would need different rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -ie' p[^, ]* *,[^,]*$'  \
<<""
AABBA, 10050, Tom marc Peter , POR
BBBAC, 10051, Eva braun, AUS
CCAHA, 10052, Jon murry , UDD
GGHAN, 10053, Taler yon, AGG
IIUSA, 10054, Raff paleen , EUS
UUGAS, 10055, Bara enty, ESP
```

---

```
AABBA, 10050, Tom marc Peter , POR
IIUSA, 10054, Raff paleen , EUS
```